# Issue when migrating Oracle query to Sql Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, oracle10g, migration

I have a simple Oracle query with a non traditional mask:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(1234567, '9G999G990D000000') VALUE_STR FROM dual
---  1.234.567,000000
```

And I am not able to convert it to Sql Server 2005, I cannot figure out how to maintain the remaining decimal places:

```
SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), CAST(1234567 AS MONEY),1)
--- 1.234.567,00
```

I would appreciate some help on an elegant way to perform this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workmate found this solution:

http://eltonbicalho.blogspot.com.br/2010/08/formatar-dinheiro-no-sql-server.html

It is working pretty fine, but is not the elegant way that I was looking for. Anyway it saved us some time.

PS: The solution is presented in portuguese.